# Why 'int' (and not 'char') is used to represent bits?

Tags: c++, c, integer, bit

I am thinking about learning some bit manipulation.
I know that memory in computers is byte-addressed. [1 byte = 8 bits]
I know that the standard is to use `int` [4 bytes] and 'twiddle' the bits in it.

But why not a '`char`' or a '`u_int8_t`'?
These are more closer to one byte size (more modular);
and have similar operations to ints. (Although, I guess `chars` are typecasted to `ints` by the compiler, piling up extra operations).

Also, if not these, then we can use '`long`' data type with 64 bit processor? (My gut says it is possible but not portable to x86).

**TL;DR - What is the rationale behind using '`int`' as data store for bits (in algorithm design sense)**.

Edit: Someone pointed that "a data store for bits" is unclear. What I meant is data-type to build a bit-wise data structure like bit array, bit field. (that what I meant for an algorithmic sense).

click [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220706030302/http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html).
Relevant - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757585/are-int-and-char-represented-using-the-same-bits-internally-by-gcc)

Comment: What makes you think that `int` has some special role here? You can use any integer type but for some bit manipulations it's strongly recommended to use **unsigned** integer types.

Comment: Code/library age is probably a significant factor here. Older code leveraged better support for but twiddling in unsigned integer types, over the character types that generally asserted a print function. For modern code look to `std::byte`

Comment: Given the time of writing of these articles I have linked and the word size of x86, `int` must have been a natural choice.

Comment: "What is the rationale behind using 'int' as data store for bits (in algorithm design sense)"

`int` is not some "data store for bits" more than any other type, so no rationale exists since your statement is false.

Comment: @Lundin All those other data types are integral under the hood. So a rationale does exist for using `int`. There are some efficiency buffs associated. (Tell us, why is it advised to use `unsigned int` over`int`.)

Comment: If you are asking why C is design in the weird manner that it keeps spitting out an `int` in all manner of situations regardless of which type you had actually intended, then yes there's a historical reason for that and it has nothing to do with bit manipulations. C originally only had the types char and int and the type system was further fleshed out over time, mostly as an afterthought. No rationale, just historical blunders.

Comment: This is for someone with similar doubts as me, I did some research. There are some caveats associated with bit operations, which you need to consider before-hand. If completely unsure and impatient, use `u_int32_t` blindly.   

I will try to wrap them up. [1] Bit operations work on any integral type (int, char, float, long...). but these integral types convert to `int` by the compiler, use of `int` is for clarity. 
[2] Shift operations work differently on signed and unsigned. 
[3] Data types sizes depend on machine the code is compiled, use fixed size for portable or word size for speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the rationale behind using 'int' as data store for bits

A long time ago, `int` represented the "word" of the processor. Let's say `int` was the datatype that the processor is able to operate the fastest on. That's why on any calculation `char` is promoted to an `int`, so if you use `char` in your code it's going to be `int` anyway, because the assumption was the processor is going to use the assembly instructions for its word.

`int` takes its history from B programming language, which only had one datatype - the processor word. When creating C the prophet Dennis Ritchie added `char` to represent one byte and `int` represented the processor word like in B programming language. That's why it was implicit `int`, so you could write `auto var;` like in B. See https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language) .

Nowadays, you would prefer `int_fastX_t`, like `int_fast8_t` or `int_fast32_t`, depending on how many bits you want to use. Or, the best would be to detect processor width at build time with the build system and compile the library optimized for specific processor word size.

> My gut says it is possible but not portable to x86).

Using a different datatype is an optimization that results in faster code on a specific architecture, not a portability issue. If you stick to what is guaranteed by C programming language, then the code will work everywhere. `long` has **at least** 32 bits - it may have 32-bits on a 64-bit processor, it may be 64 bits, it may have 36 bits, any number higher than 32 bits. It's size solely depends on the compiler and system. But nowadays only 32 and 64 matter, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models . Use `uint64_t` if you mean 64-bits.

Commonly, you would write such code with `unsigned int`. It will be 32-bit on nowadays processors, and any nowadays processor has all the instructions for 32-bits. And if you will write on xc8 compiler that has 16-bit int, your code may fail. To protect against this, you would use `int_fast32_t`.

Comment: To summarise,   
[1]. use of `int` is historic and was efficient. (we have faster alternatives like `uint_fastX_t` now).  
[2]. choice of data type is a question of optimisation than portability.    
[3]. use of `unsigned int` is highly recommend.

Comment: `uint_fastX_t` is not "faster", it is an _alias_ to a different database. It's all platform specific. [3] I would not "highly recommend" unsigned int. It all depends. If you need an unsigned database at least 16-bits long, `unsigned int` or otherwise `int_least16_t` is the type. It all depends on what you want, tools are there to use them.

Comment: Could you please comment on what portability measures should I be wary about in using bit twiddling hacks? Any major ones or any links would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `what portability measures should I be wary` I do not understand the question. Use static analyzers, compile with `-fsanitize=undefined,etc.` and with all warnings enabled, and compiler will catch almost everything for you. Compiling http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10Obvious on sdcc that has 16-bit int I get `1.c:6: warning 94: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type`.